# Why do percentage-based forecast error measures assume a meaningful zero?

Tags: forecasting

I've seen this comment made in various textbooks and papers. For example, the online textbook by Rob J Hyndman and George Athanasopoulos states at http://otexts.com/fpp/2/5/ that

> Another prob­lem with per­cent­age errors that is often over­looked is
>   that they assume a mean­ing­ful zero. For exam­ple, a per­cent­age
>   error makes no sense when mea­sur­ing the accu­racy of tem­per­a­ture
>   fore­casts on the Fahren­heit or Cel­sius scales.

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think about temperature. If I predict that tomorrow it will be 30 degrees Celsius and it is actually 31, my "percentage" error is 100*1/31 = 3.2%. However, on the Fahrenheit scale, my prediction is 86 degrees, and it is actually 87.8, giving a "percentage" error of 100*1.8/87.8 = 2.05%.

If there is a meaningful zero, such as in measurements of length, then this problem doesn't occur. A percentage error using inches will give the same answer as a percentage error using centimetres.

Comment: If we are forecasting the year in which something would occur, is there is a meaningful zero?

Comment: It depends. If you are forecasting the number of years until X occurs, then the zero is meaningful. But if you are forecasting the year on the Gregorian calendar in which X occurs, then no, it makes no sense to treat zero as meaningful as you could have used the Islamic calendar just as easily and got a different result.

Comment: @RobHyndman thanks for your input. I was wondering what your answer is about [MAPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error) error calculation metric for those multi-unit quantities you cited (temperature and length, etc. ) or can we extend your answer for PI-related evaluation metrics and classic single-target related task. please see my [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/639190/240550) you may have insightful input additionally and I can reconsider my answer.