# Potential evaluation based on the coherence of predicted value with actual data

Tags: time-series, python, prediction-interval, metric, univariate

I have the following data over time:

[image: img]

that means data collected for a single variable like CPU usage in lowest, highest, and average mode over time every 5 mins (data granularity = 5mins) like the following data frame:

```
|    | timestamp           |   min cpu |     max cpu |     avg cpu |
|---:|:--------------------|----------:|------------:|------------:|
|  0 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 |    715147 | 2.2233e+06  | 1.22957e+06 |
|  1 | 2017-01-01 00:05:00 |    700474 | 2.21239e+06 | 1.21132e+06 |
|  2 | 2017-01-01 00:10:00 |    705954 | 2.21306e+06 | 1.20663e+06 |
|  3 | 2017-01-01 00:15:00 |    688383 | 2.18757e+06 | 1.19037e+06 |
|  4 | 2017-01-01 00:20:00 |    688277 | 2.18368e+06 | 1.18099e+06 |
```

I sliced the dataframe and worked on a *univariate time-series* data problem as follows:

```
|    | timestamp           |     avg cpu |
|---:|:--------------------|------------:|
|  0 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | 1.22957e+06 |
|  1 | 2017-01-01 00:05:00 | 1.21132e+06 |
|  2 | 2017-01-01 00:10:00 | 1.20663e+06 |
|  3 | 2017-01-01 00:15:00 | 1.19037e+06 |
|  4 | 2017-01-01 00:20:00 | 1.18099e+06 |
```

I split data and applied ***PI (Prediction Interval)*** using a regression:

```
|                     |        pred |   lower_bound |   upper_bound |
|:--------------------|------------:|--------------:|--------------:|
| 2017-01-25 00:00:00 | 1.15232e+06 |   1.12482e+06 |   1.1874e+06  |
| 2017-01-25 00:05:00 | 1.14453e+06 |   1.10052e+06 |   1.18994e+06 |
| 2017-01-25 00:10:00 | 1.14033e+06 |   1.08739e+06 |   1.20795e+06 |
| 2017-01-25 00:15:00 | 1.13669e+06 |   1.0843e+06  |   1.20252e+06 |
| 2017-01-25 00:20:00 | 1.1271e+06  |   1.06837e+06 |   1.19865e+06 |
```

[image: img]
[image: img]

---

We know:

> "*Coherence: It is used for measuring the correlation between two signals. ... Coherence is the normalized cross-spectral density:*"
> $$C x y=\frac{|P x y|^2}{P x x-P y y}$$ [ref.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-plot-the-coherence-between-two-signals-in-python/)

**question:**

Does one evaluate something ***potentially*** meaningful based on the ***coherence*** of `predictions['upper_bound']` or `predictions['pred']` with actual test data `data_test['avg cpu']`?

[image: img]

---

code:

````py
#!pip install skforecast
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error

from sklearn.linear_model import  Ridge, #Lasso, LinearRegression
from skforecast.ForecasterAutoreg import ForecasterAutoreg

# Create and train forecaster
# ==============================================================================
forecaster = ForecasterAutoreg(
                 regressor = Ridge(alpha=0.1, random_state=765),
                 lags      =  288
             )

forecaster.fit(y=data_train['avg cpu'])

# Prediction intervals
# ==============================================================================
predictions = forecaster.predict_interval(
                  steps    = steps,
                  interval = [1, 99],
                  n_boot   = 500
              )

# Prediction error
# ==============================================================================
error_mse2 = mean_squared_error(
                y_true = data_test['avg cpu'],
                y_pred = predictions['upper_bound']
            )

print(f"Test error (MSE): {error_mse2}")

# Plot forecasts with prediction intervals and coherence of signals
# ==============================================================================
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 3))
plt.ylabel('cpu', fontsize=15)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
plt.xlabel('timestamp', fontsize=15, color='darkred')
cossignal1=data_test['avg cpu'].plot(ax=ax,       label='Test-set',                    color='orange',         linestyle='-.', marker="p")
cossignal2=predictions['upper_bound'].plot(ax=ax, label=f"predictions['upper_bound']" ,     color='darkred')
predictions['pred'].plot(ax=ax, label=f"predictions['pred']")
plt.title("Signals")
#place legend in top right corner
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.6,.9), loc="upper right")
plt.show()

# Store the value of correlation in a
# variable say 'cor' using the following code:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 3))
cor=plt.cohere(data_test['avg cpu'],predictions['upper_bound'], c='g')
plt.title(f"Coherence of Signals: predictions['upper_bound'] and data_test['avg cpu']")
# plot the coherence graph
ax.legend(['Coherence'])
plt.show()


# Store the value of correlation in a
# variable say 'cor' using the following code:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 3))
cor=plt.cohere(data_test['avg cpu'],predictions['pred'], c='g')
plt.title(f"Coherence of Signals: predictions['pred'] and data_test['avg cpu']")
# plot the coherence graph
ax.legend(['Coherence'])
plt.show()
```
````

Comment: Judging from your third-to-last plot, your predictions seem to be biased: they are systematically too low. In such a situation, I would be careful about any correlation-based measure, because you can have high correlation and high bias at the same time. Prediction intervals are typically assessed using [the interval or Winkler score](https://forecasting-encyclopedia.com/theory.html#point_forecast_accuracy_measures).

Comment: @StephanKolassa thanks for your input. You're right about creating a minimal example using `skforecast` python package for time-series analytics. Within this package regardless of the `regressor` one can choose (in my case `Ridge`) within the `ForecasterAutoreg()` class, *prediction Interval (PI)* results return by using `predict_interval()`. Maybe using an inappropriate regressor like `Ridge` outputs this biased low prediction. maybe the PI approach within causes it. I included the Python codes for better understanding.

Comment: Then **PI results** are computed by the [**bootstrapping**](https://joaquinamatrodrigo.github.io/skforecast/0.11.0/user_guides/probabilistic-forecasting.html) process, which after reading the documentation I don't how works and create a separate [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/128101/69263) to understand it. Maybe you can assist me to understand it.